# Renting an apartment in Bergamo, Italy

Tags: accommodation, italy, rental, bergamo

What are good places on the web to research the apartment situation in Bergamo, Italy (and its surroundings) and are there any recommendations you can give to someone who is coming from another country (Croatia, a little swim to the east) and will be staying there for a period of two, maybe three months?

Comment: Note that questions/problems related to moving somewhere permanently are off-topic for the “travel” site.

Comment: @Annoyed - Not moving. Just staying there for a longer period of time. I don't know how to put it better so it fits between the two. But that part is irrelevant, really.

Comment: Well, yes and no, you would not necessarily look for a vacation rental for a week on the same website than a place to stay for several years. It's not so much that I care personally, your question seems fine and I upvoted it but I wanted to clarify the fact that answers on this site would not cover the regular housing market.

Comment: @Annoyed  Understand. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

You can search on http://casa.it or http://kijiji.it for "Affitto Temporaneo" or mailing local real estate agencies (most famous are http://tecnocasa.it http://tempocasa.it) asking for apartments that match your needs, specifying you're there for max 2/3 months.

I strongly suggest you to search for a room in a shared flat, by the way. It will be cheaper and you'll have less constraints.

Comment: Room / an interesting idea. Can you tell me (just a bit ) more about it. I've never lived in that kind of accomodation. How does that work? Not only roommate, but permits related.

Comment: Usually in Italy renting a room is easier (a.k.a. informal contracts) than renting an entire apartment. I strongly suggest you to check for http://www.kijiji.it/case/stanze-e-posti-letto/bergamo-annunci-bergamo/ and contact the poster of the ads you like. Usually you have a private room with shared expenses (water, etc...) kitchen & bathroom(s). Some of them have a "tutto incluso" (all inclusive) formulas: you pay x for rent and everything else.

Comment: One other suggestion: check for the room in advance before renting it. For the first 2/3 days if I were in you I'll stay in an hotel.